# Modal window, but only for some windows

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a form.
This form can open an editor, which extends from Form.
The editor has links you click, which opens a modal form to define that link.

```
// Main form
private void OnMainForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Editor editor = new Editor();
    editor.Show();
}



// editor
private void OnEditorLink_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LinkConfigDialog linkDialog = new LinkConfigDialog();
    linkDialog.ShowModal();
}
```

This ensures that the user cannot click, and attempt to modify, other links (or the same link) which editing one already. This is by design.

However, now I wish to let people open multiple Editors. I still want the modal forms to work, but ONLY for those editors, not for the entire application.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: why do not just temporary hide caller window, and on close of the dialog, make it visible again, like before. ?

Comment: I never hid the caller window, and I don't want to. +1 for a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write a method in your `Editor` class that "freezes" your Editor dialog. For example, by disabling the controls and so. Then you can call that method when a `LinkDialog` is opened. This way you can have multiple `Editor` instances that are only disabled by their own `LinkDialog`s. You can have another method that re-enables the controls that will be called when the `LinkDialog` is being closed.

Comment: Yeah, a bool that flags when the window is up, and returns all click events when the bool is true on the editor. Not exactly ideal, as it won't catch every case, but works!

Comment: What do you mean with "it won't catch every case"?

Comment: If somebody adds a new click event to do something, that check won't be there unless they remember to add it.

Comment: You can create a public method in your `Editor` class that disables it (whichever way you like). And you can take an `Editor` instance in the constructor of your `LinkDialog`, it can take that `Editor` instance and call the disable method, and when the `LinkDialog` is being closed it can call another public method that enables the `EditorDialog`. I don't understand what you need the events for in this specific case.